# RichTextBox.GetCharFromPosition returns incorrect character when using the text box dimensions

Tags: c#

I am attempting to find the start and end characters of text visible in a RichTextBox.  To find the start I pass the coordinates (0,0) into RichTextBox.GetCharFromPosition(Point), which returns the first char visible. In the code chunk below it returns 'a', which is correct.

The issue is when I try and find the last character.  To find the last character, I tried to use the width and height of the control as coordinates so it would return the character closest to the bottom right corner, which should be the furthest right character of the last line.  The remarks section for TextBoxBase.GetCharFromPosition, which RichTextBox inherits from, states:

> If the location specified in the pt parameter is outside the client area of the control, the first character of the string closest to the point specified in pt is returned.[0]

When I pass in the width and height of the control as the point, it will return the **first** character of the last line instead of the **last** character of the last line even though the last character should be closer to the corner.  In the example below, it returns 'g' instead of 'i'.

What is confusing is that when I subtract 4 from the height, the correct character is returned.  If you subtract 1,2 or 3 it returns 'i' but once it is greater than 3 it returns 'g'.  For any number greater than the height, it still returns 'i'.

My best guess is that is has something to do with the size of the border of the control and subtracting 4 measures from inside the control rather than on the edge or outside.  The same thing also happens with RichTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Point)[1], where it will return the index of the first char instead of the last char of the last line.  Any idea what is going on here?

```
RichTextBox rtb=new RichTextBox();
rtb.Width=300;
rtb.Height=100;
rtb.Text="abc"+"\n"+"def"+"\n"+"ghi";
/* Text will look like:
   abc
   def
   ghi
*/
//This one behaves correctly.
char firstCharacter=rtb.GetCharFromPosition(new Point(0,0));
Assert.AreEqual('a',firstCharacter);

//This uses rtb.Height and will return the incorrect character.
char fullHeightChar=rtb.GetCharFromPosition(new Point(rtb.Width,rtb.Height));
Assert.AreEqual('g',fullHeightChar);

//This uses a number much greater than rtb.Height
char largeHeightChar=rtb.GetCharFromPosition(new Point(rtb.Width,500));
Assert.AreEqual('g',largeHeightChar);

//This one uses (rtb.Height-4) and returns the correct character.
char subHeightChar=rtb.GetCharFromPosition(new Point(rtb.Width,rtb.Height-4));    
Assert.AreEqual('i',subHeightChar);
```

[0]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getcharfromposition?view=netframework-4.7.2
[1]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the microsoft documentation you already viewed:

> If the location specified in the pt parameter is outside the **client
>   area** of the control, the first character of the string closest to the
>   point specified in pt is returned.

So you need to pass the point at the corner of client area of the `RichTextBoX` control with is the point at the `ClientSize`:

```
char fullHeightChar = rtb.GetCharFromPosition(new Point(rtb.ClientSize));
```

Comment: I have been banging my head on this for weeks, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help